# Google signin button - PHP

Tags: php, sign

I was implementing Google signin button at the server side.

I am getting a syntax error at the line:

```
$tokenInfo = json_decode($client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());
```

However this is directly taken from https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow.

I am new to PHP and hence not able to understand these PHP syntax clearly.
What does the symbol :: mean? Does this require any particular version of php?

pl help

Comment: Static class method call.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Thanks friends. It is clear now that it works only in 5.3 or above. what is the equivalent of $client::getIo() in 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901775/google-login-api-problems/27006723) which I think may be your problem.

In the line you are having trouble with:

```
$tokenInfo = json_decode($google::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());
```

`::` change to `->`. and `getIo()` should be changed to `getAuth()` due to (I think) a migration within the api.

After that, I encountered another error in which I changed:
`if ($token->error)` to `if(isset($tokenInfo->error))`

Good Luck!