# Google+ login api problems

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus

I'm trying to implement google+ oauth2 login in my app and I am currently running into a few issues.

I am mainly following what is written [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)

It seems like the example is using  a lot of libraries like twig, but I'm using maining pure php, and I don't think that part is causing any errors

The first issue I faced was that `Google_HTTPRequest was not found`.
I read somewhere that composer names it `Google_HTTP_Request`, so I changed that and it seemed to have fixed that problem.

Then php was complaining that I was making a static call on a nonstatic function `getIo()`.
So I changed to `::` to `->` because that was what made sense to me.

Then I am getting the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Google_IO_Curl::authenticatedRequest()
```

Which probably has something to do with what I changed.

The code I am running is

```
$google = new Google_Client();
$google->setApplicationName('Hamster Weebly');
$google->setClientId('CLIEnTID');
$google->setClientSecret('himitsudesuyo');
$google->setRedirectUri('postmessage');


$google->authenticate($_POST['AUTH_CODE']);
$token = json_decode($google->getAccessToken());

//$attrbutes = $google->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, '375022219321-us60lmg2cmeoj1aqpl784t7pbl1kg3jv.apps.googleusercontent.com')->getAttributes();

//error_log($attrbutes['payload']['sub']);

$reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' . $token->access_token;
$req = new Google_Http_Request($reqUrl);

$tokenInfo = json_decode($google->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());


if ($token->error)
{
    http_response_code(500);
    exit;
}

// Make sure the token we got is for the intended user.
if ($tokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode("Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID");
    exit;
}
// Make sure the token we got is for our app.
if ($tokenInfo->audience != CLIENT_ID) 
{
    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode("Token's client ID does not match app");
    exit;
}
```

What is my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
$tokenInfo = json_decode($google->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());
```

`getIo()` should be changed to `getAuth()` due to (I think) a migration within the api.

After that, I encountered another error in which I changed:
`if ($token->error)` to `if ( isset($tokenInfo->error) )`

Good Luck!

Comment: getAuth seems to run without error, but tokeninfo seems to be empty.
Is there any documentation for this?

Thanks

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, accept it as the answer. ;-)

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Google really need to update their API manuals ... This is the second time I've been stuck using their depreciated manuals Lol